How to modify JetBrainsClientDist path on JetBrains Gateway
The JetBrians Gateway download JetBrains Client to local path is "%LOCALAPPDATA%\JetBrains\JetBrainsClientDist" directorr on my windows system.
How can I change it to my other path like "e:\JetBrains\JetBrainsClientDist".
I try modify custom properties:
idea.config.path=E:\JetBrains\config
idea.system.path=E:\JetBrains\system
idea.plugins.path=E:\JetBrains\plugins
idea.log.path=E:\JetBrains\log

